# What does it mean: "Strings of Constraints"

Tags: applications

I am reading [an article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10556780310001610484) in the field of applied mathematics. I've ran into a sentence that reads:

> The string-averaging algorithm projects a point sequentially along
>   several independent ***strings of constraints***.

I really don't get what does it mean by the *"strings of constraints"*! Please help me understand it!

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: A non-paywall version of the linked paper is available [here](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/citations;jsessionid=F4E3EF09016BA18E0772DD82A63E2B3B?doi=10.1.1.399.6223).